# aws: error: argument operation: put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Getting following error for put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration  :

```
[root@ADM-PROD-OMNI noc-scripts]# aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket noc-try --lifecycle-configuration  lifecycle.json
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [parameters]
aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

abort-multipart-upload                   | complete-multipart-upload
copy-object                              | create-bucket
create-multipart-upload                  | delete-bucket
delete-bucket-cors                       | delete-bucket-lifecycle
delete-bucket-policy                     | delete-bucket-replication
delete-bucket-tagging                    | delete-bucket-website
delete-object                            | delete-objects
get-bucket-acl                           | get-bucket-cors
get-bucket-lifecycle                     | get-bucket-location
get-bucket-logging                       | get-bucket-notification
get-bucket-notification-configuration    | get-bucket-policy
get-bucket-replication                   | get-bucket-request-payment
get-bucket-tagging                       | get-bucket-versioning
get-bucket-website                       | get-object
get-object-acl                           | get-object-torrent
head-bucket                              | head-object
list-buckets                             | list-multipart-uploads
list-object-versions                     | list-objects
list-parts                               | put-bucket-acl
put-bucket-cors                          | put-bucket-lifecycle
put-bucket-logging                       | put-bucket-notification
put-bucket-notification-configuration    | put-bucket-policy
put-bucket-replication                   | put-bucket-request-payment
put-bucket-tagging                       | put-bucket-versioning
put-bucket-website                       | put-object
put-object-acl                           | restore-object
upload-part                              | upload-part-copy
wait                                     | help
```

But

get-bucket-lifecycle is working this means my aws is configured :

```
[root@ADM-PROD-OMNI noc-scripts]# aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle --bucket 4sm-wrapup
RULES    clear multipart failed files           Enabled

**OR**

[root@ADM-PROD-OMNI noc-scripts]# aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle --bucket noc-try

A client error (NoSuchLifecycleConfiguration) occurred when calling the GetBucketLifecycle operation: The lifecycle configuration does not exist
```

Also tried :

```
 [root@ADM-PROD-OMNI noc-scripts]# aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle --bucket noc-try --lifecycle-configuration  lifecycle.json

    Error parsing parameter '--lifecycle-configuration': Expected: '=', received: '.' for input:
    lifecycle.json
             ^
```

Please let me know what is wrong here ?

Comment: can we see your lifecycle.json?

Comment: I used this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTlifecycle.html

Comment: @zoubida13  
My lifecycle.json : <LifecycleConfiguration> <Rule> <ID>clear multipart failed files</ID> <Prefix>S3 buckets/</Prefix> <Status>Enabled</Status> <AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload> <DaysAfterInitiation>30</DaysAfterInitiation> </AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload> </Rule> </LifecycleConfiguration>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first example it is pretty obvious that the method "put-bucket-lifecycle-configuration" does not exist, and you need to be using "put-bucket-lifecycle" instead, which you said you also tried and received a different error.

Different errors are good!

The new error suggests improper syntax when calling your .json configuration file, and/or improper structured JSON.

Here is documentation on the "put-bucket-lifecycle": [put-bucket-lifecycle](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-lifecycle.html)

Here is an example of calling a .json config file:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle --bucket my-bucket --lifecycle-configuration file://lifecycle.json
```

Here is an example of JSON file:

```
{
  "Rules": [
    {
      "ID": "Move to Glacier after sixty days (objects in logs/2015/)",
      "Prefix": "logs/2015/",
      "Status": "Enabled",
      "Transition": {
        "Days": 60,
        "StorageClass": "GLACIER"
      }
    },
    {
      "Expiration": {
        "Date": "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      "ID": "Delete 2014 logs in 2016.",
      "Prefix": "logs/2014/",
      "Status": "Enabled"
    }
  ]
}
```

***BELOW JSON FILE IS TESTED AND WORKS AS SHOWN IN THE SUBSEQUENT SCREENSHOTS:***

```
{
    "Rules": [
        {
          "ID": "multipart-upload-rule",
          "Prefix": "noc-try",
          "Status": "Enabled",
          "AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload": { "DaysAfterInitiation": 3 }
        }
    ]
}
```

***CLI COMMAND TO CREATE LIFECYCLE CONFIG USING ABOVE JSON FILE:***

```
aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle --bucket testbucket1478921 --lifecycle-configuration file://c:/tmp/test.json
```

[image][image][image]

Comment: I don't want to move to Glacier ! I want it to clear multipart failed files ie : <LifecycleConfiguration>
    <Rule>
        <ID>clear multipart failed files</ID>
        <Prefix>S3 buckets/</Prefix>
        <Status>Enabled</Status>
        <AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload>
          <DaysAfterInitiation>30</DaysAfterInitiation>
        </AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload>
    </Rule>
</LifecycleConfiguration>

Comment: [root@ADM-PROD-OMNI noc-scripts]# aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle --bucket noc-try --lifecycle-configuration  file://lifecycle.json

substring not found
Got this error for this jason file : <LifecycleConfiguration>
    <Rule>
        <ID>clear-multipart-failed-files</ID>
        <Prefix>whole bucket/</Prefix>
        <Status>Enabled</Status>
        <AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload>
          <DaysAfterInitiation>3</DaysAfterInitiation>
        </AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload>
    </Rule>
</LifecycleConfiguration>

Comment: Getting this error : [root@ADM-PROD-OMNI noc-scripts]#  aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle --bucket noc-try --lifecycle-configuration  file://lifecycle1.json
Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in LifecycleConfiguration.Rules[0]: "AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload", must be one of: Expiration, ID, Prefix, Status, Transition, NoncurrentVersionTransition, NoncurrentVersionExpiration

Comment: For following json file : [root@ADM-PROD-OMNI noc-scripts]# cat  lifecycle1.json
{
    "Rules": [
        {
            "ID": "clear-multipart-failed-files",
            "Prefix": "noc-try",
            "Status": "Enabled",
      },
        "AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload": {
        "DaysAfterInitiation": 30
      }
            }

    ]
}

Comment: As stated in the original answer you had 2 problems with your attempt. You were using wrong method from the CLI command prompt, and your JSON file was not formatted correctly. The original answer has been updated to include the correct CLI command syntax AND the correct JSON format. As you can see from the screenshots, it was tested, and it works!

Comment: Sorry but getting same error : [root@ADM-PROD-OMNI noc-scripts]# aws s3api put-bucket-lifecycle --bucket noc-try --lifecycle-configuration  file://lifecycle.json

Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in LifecycleConfiguration.Rules[0]: "AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload", must be one of: Expiration, ID, Prefix, Status, Transition, NoncurrentVersionTransition, NoncurrentVersionExpiration

Comment: used ur json file : [root@ADM-PROD-OMNI noc-scripts]# cat lifecycle.json
{
    "Rules": [
        {
          "ID": "multipart-upload-rule",
          "Prefix": "noc-try",
          "Status": "Enabled",
          "AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload": { "DaysAfterInitiation": 3 }
        }
    ]
}
Still got same error